# How do I lock Run Configuration in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse Juno SR2 (and previous versions as well) regularly breaks my Run Configurations. It removes some of the program arguments, changes ports, etc.

Is there any way to lock Run Configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Run Configuration dialog, go to the Common tab.  Select 'Shared file'.  There you can save your run configuration to your project, even place it under source control.  That way you can be sure it is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the "Common" tab of the run configuration, where you can save a run configuration as "shared file" directly in your workspace. Then you can make it read-only, and additionally put it under version control like a normal file and restore it in case of problems.

That said, normally Eclipse plugins do not modify existing run configurations once you have manually changed them, so maybe there is another problem.